# How do you integrate Matlab code in a CICD pipeline incl. deployment to a cloud cluster?

Tags: docker, matlab, kubernetes, gitlab, cicd

I am looking into integrating Matlab with our CICD pipelines (GitLab for Enterprise but also interested possibilities related to the free tier). Some of our researchers still heavily rely on Matlab and various (some paid) toolboxes. I would like to use their code to build cloud services (e.g. backed by Kubernetes Pods) that will process the data. The workflow can be described as follows:

1. Write code with Matlab full environment incl. proprietary toolboxes
2. Commit code
3. Push code to GitLab
4. Build binary with MC SDK
5. Create Docker image with MCR
6. Run tests on Matlab code
7. Deploy to Kubernetes cloud

I do realize this is rather vague but I am actually looking into the general approach just to see if it's worth the trouble at all.

To my knowledge in this case I need to consider two main things:

- **Compiling Matlab code** - unless one is to deploy a full fledged Matlab environment, one needs the licensed and paid Matlab Compiler SDK
- **Testing/Deploying Matlab code** - from what I know running compiled code (either as a DLL used by another application or as a mex64 binary) only needs the Matlab Compiler Runtime, which is free of charge and can be deployed as a part of e.g. a Docker image (one can find official Docker images for latest Matlab version on DockerHub or even build older ones with e.g. [sources such as this one](https://github.com/demartis/matlab_runtime_docker))

I do know that MathWorks wants a piece of the pie so they also provide services including such that are cloud-related. However all of that is anything but free so I'd like to know how people normally go about this situation.

Comment: Can you clarify what your requirements are?

Comment: I added the workflow that I have in mind. As for the specific requirements I am looking for a general approach. Once I see if something like this is even possible I can adapt it to the different cases we have. The only difficult part in terms of code is when using the parallel toolbox for distributed computing including CUDA. I know that Docker etc. support it but I am yet to try it out with MCR itself.